# Memory access time

Tags: operating-system

When we calculate the effective memory access time where TLB hit ratio,TLB access time and memory access time is given, then we use formula as:
 Effective memory access time=TLB hit ratio*(TLB Access Time+Memory acess time)+(1-TLB Hit ratio)*(TLB Access Time+2*Memory acess time).
then why we multiply Memory access time by 2?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Comment: You multiply by 2 because for each memory access, you access your main memory twice.

In first you check TLB, if you find in which frame it sits, then all good you can immediately go there and bring the instruction, otherwise you will have to access your Page Table in memory and then access your main memory again to fetch the instruction.

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 0):

We multiply the memory access time by 2 because of the following steps:

**1**.Because `TLB` does not contain the `translation` for the given `virutal address`,so step 2.

**2**. First memory access to the `physical memory` to access the `page table` which converts `virtual address` to `physical address`.

**3**. After accessing the `page table` , the `virtual address` is converted to `physical address`, and then, we go to `physical memory` again to access the corresponding `physical memory` frame(or page).